# Access violation whenever i change QTableWidget.item(row, col)

Tags: c++, qt, access-violation, qtablewidget

I used `QTableWidget` in my program, and tried to set the background color of some certain cells, however every time i got nothing except `Access violation`.

```
QTableWidget* tTable = new QTableWidget();
tTable->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
tTable->item(0, 0)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::red);
```

I'm using MSVC 2010.

Comment: Do you know if the access violation is on tTable or whats returned from item's return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setRowCount`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#rowCount-prop) and [`setColumnCount`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#columnCount-prop) in order to set the number of rows and columns for your table.

```
QTableWidget* tTable = new QTableWidget();
tTable->setRowCount(1);
tTable->setColumnCount(1);
tTable->setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem());
tTable->item(0, 0)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::red);
```

Alternatively provide the number of rows and columns of the table in the [constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#QTableWidget-2)

```
QTableWidget* tTable = new QTableWidget(1,1,this);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, i even thought that item() is not accessible